# Deleting specific line from file in c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, file-handling

I want the user to enter the roll number of a student, and then inside my file I want to delete that specific record.

Lets say my file contains the following information

```
1 Abhi 92
2 Ravi 89
3 Kiran 45
```

The user enters 2, then I want the file to change to:

```
1 Abhi 92
3 Kiran 45
```

How is it possible?

**EDIT**:

It is a part of this project, I want to create another case which says delete:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class Students
    {
        private:

            int roll_number;
            char name[80],dummy;
            float marks;
            char grade;
        public:
            void read_info()
            {
                calc_grade();
                cout<<roll_number<<"\t"<<name<<"\t\t\t"<<marks<<"\t\t"<<grade<<endl<<endl;
            }
            void write_info()
            {
                cout<<"Roll Number: ";
                cin>>roll_number;
                cin.get(dummy);
                cout<<"Name: ";
                cin.get(name,80);
                cin.get(dummy);
                start:
                cout<<"Marks: ";
                cin>>marks;
                if(marks < 0 || marks > 100)
                {
                    cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
                    goto start;
                }
                cin.get(dummy);
            }
            void calc_grade()
            {
                if(marks>=80)
                    grade = 'A';
                else if(marks>=60)
                    grade = 'B';
                else if(marks>=40)
                    grade = 'C';
                else if(marks>=20)
                    grade = 'D';
            }
            int return_roll()
            {
                return roll_number;
            }
            float return_marks()
            {
                return marks;
            }
    };
int main()
    {
        int start_swit;
        do
        {
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\t\t\t\t\tStudents Database"<<endl;
            cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            Students s;
            fstream fil;
            char ch;
            int search_rn;
            cout<<"1.Read\t\t2.Write\t\t3.Specific student\t\t4.Topper"<<endl<<endl;
            cin>>start_swit;
            switch(start_swit)
                {
                case 1:
                    {
                        system("cls");
                        fil.open("studentdata.bin",ios::in|ios::binary);
                        cout<<"Roll.N\t  Name\t\t\tMarks\t\tGrade"<<endl;
                        cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                        while(fil.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))
                        {
                            s.read_info();
                        }
                        fil.close();
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        system("cls");
                        fil.open("studentdata.bin",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
                        ch = 'y';
                        do{
                            s.write_info();
                            fil.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
                            cout<<"Do you want to enter more records?: ";
                            cin>>ch;
                        }
                        while(ch == 'y');
                        fil.close();
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        int found = 0;
                        fil.open("studentdata.bin",ios::in|ios::binary);
                        cout<<"Enter the roll number of the student: ";
                        cin>>search_rn;
                        while(fil.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))
                              {
                                  if(search_rn == s.return_roll())
                                  {
                                      cout<<"Roll.N\t\tName\t\tMarks\t\tGrade"<<endl;
                                      cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                                      s.read_info();
                                      found = 1;
                                      break;
                                  }
                              }
                        if(found != 1)
                            cout<<"Student not found"<<endl;
                        fil.close();
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        float highest_marks = 0;
                        int roll_high;
                        fil.open("studentdata.bin",ios::in|ios::binary);
                        while(fil.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))
                            {
                                if(s.return_marks()>= highest_marks)
                                    {
                                            highest_marks = s.return_marks();
                                            roll_high = s.return_roll();
                                    }
                            }
                        fil.close();
                        fil.open("studentdata.bin",ios::in|ios::binary);
                        while(fil.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))
                              {
                                  if(roll_high == s.return_roll())
                                  {
                                      cout<<"Roll.N\t\tName\t\tMarks\t\tGrade"<<endl;
                                      cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                                      s.read_info();
                                      break;
                                  }
                              }
                        fil.close();
                        break;
                    }

                }//switch end
            }// Do while loop end
            while(start_swit>=1 && start_swit<=4);
        return 0;
    }// main() end
```

Comment: Read all into a string. Do your formatting. Write back,

Comment: Goto? Maybe mix up of read and write? Plain C-Style char array instead of ````std::string````? ````using namespace std;````?  Please reconsider

Comment: Hi I'm learning from various sources and merely doing what I have learnt

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int deleteAtLine(const std::string file_name, std::vector::size_type lineNumber){
    //the memory storage medium
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    //Reading the file to the storage
    {
        //opening the file for reading from it
        std::ifstream file(file_name);
        //checking if the file has been opened correctly
        if (not file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "can't open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        //Reading
        for (std::string one_line; std::getline(file, one_line);lines.push_back(one_line));
    }
    //Writing the storage to the file
    {
        //opening the file for writing to it
        std::ofstream file(file_name);
        //checking if the file has been opened correctly
        if (not file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "can't open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        //finding out the number of the lines
        const auto lines_count = lines.size();
        //writing
        for (std::string::size_type lines_counter(0); lines_counter < lines_count;){
            //checking the line number and writing the extra line if it is needed
            if(lines_counter != lineNumber) file << lines[lines_counter++] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    //returning 0 if there was no error to this stage 
    return 0;
}
```

First you open the file for reading:

```
        //opening the file for reading from it
        std::ifstream file(file_name);
        //checking if the file has been opened correctly
        if (not file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "can't open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
```

then read all the file lines and store then in the vector:

```
        //Reading
        for (std::string one_line; std::getline(file, one_line);lines.push_back(one_line));
```

after closing the previous (read-only) version of the file, you open it again for writing, this time:

```
        //opening the file for writing to it
        std::ofstream file(file_name);
        //checking if the file has been opened correctly
        if (not file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "can't open the file " << file_name << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
```

then put back all the lines except the desired line:

```
        for (std::string::size_type lines_counter(0); lines_counter < lines_count;){
            //checking the line number and writing the extra line if it is needed
            if(lines_counter != lineNumber) file << lines[lines_counter++] << std::endl;
}
```

You can use this function like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::string file_name;
    std::string::size_type lineNumber;

    std::cin >> file_name;
    std::cin >> lineNumber;

    return deleteAtLine(file_name, lineNumber);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This deletes a line at a given line number, but not THE line which contains the students roll number.

Comment: @ArminMontigny, yes you are right. But I think that was what he asked for! "The user enters 2 then i want the file to change to ..." . I addition, he can keep track of entries individually by some entry-counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the file in-place, i.e. without loading the entire file into memory, editing it, and then overwriting the old file, you could possibly use random-access methods to overwrite the deleted student's info with dummy info that will not be read. This will clutter up your file a bit is all. I haven't tested this code, but the general idea is to use the seekg and tellg member functions of fstream.

```
case 5:
    {
        int found = 0;
        long pos;   //stores file pointer position
        fil.open("studentdata.bin",ios::in|ios::binary);
        cout<<"Enter the roll number of the student to delete: ";
        cin>>search_rn;
        while(fil.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))
              {
                  if(search_rn == s.return_roll())
                  {
                      //returns file's write position
                      pos = fil.tellp();
                      //rewind the file pointer (sizeof type????)
                      fil.seekg((pos - sizeof(s)), ios::cur); //not ios::beg);
                      s.delete_info();
                      //overwrite the old date with dummy data
                      fil.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
                      fil.close();
                      found = 1;
                      break;
                  }
              }
        if(found != 1)
            cout<<"Student not found"<<endl;
        fil.close();
        break;
    }

//add this class method:
void delete_info() 
{
    roll_number = -1;
    name = "deleted";
    marks = 0.0;
    grade = ' ';
}
```

Again this code isn't tested but I think the offset is correct, as long as sizeof(s) returns a long.  It might be cleaner to do a complete file read-into-memory, edit, and overwrite operation as the above answer suggests however.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of homeworks expect you to be able to do several things:

- Create a structure to store <student> information
- Read students from file into a vector / array / etc
- Find and remove the desired element
- Write the modified vector / array / whatever of <student> back to file

This is normal. Efforts to modify files using other methods will not help you learn what you are supposed to be learning.

In fact, this is the way you should typically approach *all* file I/O. The only difference between files is the structure you use to store file data.

Glancing at your code you are mixing storing a single record with a full database (vector / array / list / whatever) of them. Make yourself a struct / class / whatever for a *single* student, plus methods to read and write a single student to and from a stream.

Then add the ability to read an entire file. It will invariably look something like:

```
std::vector <Student> students;
Student student;
while (f >> student)  // or whatever function you create to read a student
{
  students.push_back( student );
}
```

Arrays (if you are using C or not allowed to use vectors yet) work similarly:

```
Student students[MAX_STUDENTS];
int num_students = 0;
while ((num_students < MAX_STUDENTS) and (f >> students[num_students]))
{
  num_students += 1;
}
```

The trick is to create the functions that will read a single student. Using the extraction operator (as I have exampled above):

```
std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & ins, Student & student )
{
  // use whatever method you think best to get a line from
  // 'ins' and parse it into the 'student' object. When 
  // done, return the stream:
  return ins;
}
```

Your function to write a student data is likewise simple:

```
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & outs, const Student & student )
{
  outs << student.roll_number;
  outs << student.name;
  outs << student.grade;
  outs << "\n";
  return outs;
}
```

This is how to do it.